# When to use public modifier for a class field in OOP?

Tags: java, c#, oop, public, access-modifiers

When programming in OO languages like C# or Java, is there a good situation where declaring a public field inside a class is actually valid (I myself always use a property for not making the user of the class depend on the data and to support data protection)?
Otherwise, it feels weird that C# for example allows you to do so.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Short answer: `static final` fields with immutable values are often public, as they represent constants which pertain to the containing class.  No other fields should ever be public.  Just because a compiler allows something does not mean it’s a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C# coding conventions `public field` [should be used sparingly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions):

```
// A public field, these should be used sparingly
public bool IsValid;
```

Why? I think because of:

- can be edited by any other user of class
- if you want to add some logic to field, then you need to create property instead of field. By doing this, you will break a contract of class
- it is not possible to override variable

However, there is a case when you need to have field as [@VGR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831987/vgr) said:

```
public const string foo = "";
```